# html links in handlebars templates

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

If I create Handlebars templates for a Backbone app like this (inside a view with string concatenation), using handlebars.js, the links are displaying properly and everything is working as intended.

```
template: Handlebars.compile(
        '<ul>' + 
        '{{#each models}}<li><a href="#" class="linko" data-retail="{{attributes.question}}">{{attributes.question}} {{attributes.uk}}{{attributes._id}}</a> ' +
        '<a href="#" class="updato" data-retail="{{attributes._id}}">update this</a> '+
        '<a href="#" class="delete" data-retail="{{attributes._id}}">delete</a>{{/each}} </li>' + 
        '</ul>' 

    ),
```

However, if I follow the instructions in the Lynda tutorial I'm using and replace Handlebars.js with handlebars.runtime.js and put the template in a file `nameoftemplate.handlebars` as below and compile it from the render action of a view like this

```
this.$el.html(Handlebars.templates.menu(this.collection));
```

**menu.handlebars**

```
<ul>
        {{#each models}}<li>
        <a href="#" class="linko" data-retail="{{attributes.question}}">{{attributes.question}} {{attributes.uk}}{{attributes._id}}</a> 
        <a href="#" class="updato" data-retail="{{attributes._id}}">update this</a> 
        <a href="#" class="delete" data-retail="{{attributes._id}}">delete</a>{{/each}} </li>
</ul>
```

then the links are no longer displaying. Why is it that html links are working (as in the sense of displaying as a link) on the one but not the other?

Update
When I console.log the template that's not displaying as expected it just shows a bunch of list elements, no links

```
console.log(Handlebars.templates.menu(this.collection));
<ul>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li>r</li><li>fd</li><li>mike</li><li>afsd</li><li>fdsa</li><li>asfa</li><li>dkd</li><li>aff</li><li>asdf</li><li>mini</li><li>ff</li><li>dafs</li><li>mike</li><li>afdsaf</li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ul>
```

However, when I do it the other way, with the concatenated template defined in the view (rather than in a separate file), the `li` tags are full of links and other expected data

```
console.log(this.template(this.collection));



<ul><li><a href="#" class="linko" data-retail="1">1 I heard a bloke on the train say that tomorrow&#x27;s trains will be delayed.526c0e21977a67d6966dc763</a> <a href="#" class="updato" data-retail="526c0e21977a67d6966dc763">update this</a> <a href="#" class="delete" data-retail="526c0e21977a67d6966dc763">delete</a><li>
```

Comment: I am not familiar Handlebars, but I see one mistake. You have `{{/each}} </li>` instead of `</li> {{/each}}`

Comment: @leestex thanks for pointing that out, however, doesn't fix the problem, namely that the links aren't showing when I do the template the second way

Comment: What comes out of the `Handlebars.templates.menu` call? Nothing at all? An empty `<ul></ul>`? Something else?

Comment: @muistooshort not sure how to check that. if I call it without the collection as a parameter like this `console.log(Handlebars.templates.menu());`, I get this error `  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined ` Of course if I just pass it without calling it to console log `console.log(Handlebars.templates.menu);` it prints the Handlebars code

Comment: You could `console.log(Handlebars.templates.menu(this.collection))` and look at the text it produces.

Comment: @muistooshort good thought. Thanks, actually, it logs the same thing that's printed to screen except it shows the `li` tags. I'll update the OP.

Comment: How exactly are you pre-compiling the template? Have you tried a simpler version of your template? Have you looked at the function that gets put in `Handlebars.templates.menu`?

Comment: @muistooshort, after reviewing the Lydna video, the problem was that I wasn't pre-compiling the template properly using the Handlebars package for node. Thanks for the tip